# android Facebook oAuth exception?

Tags: android, facebook

I am getting this response from facebook while trying to postwall.
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException"}}

can anybody help me what can be a problem?

Comment: you are not authenticating the right way... show us your code

Comment: how should the community be able to help you if you send the code just to a single person? why not include it to your question

Comment: exactly as martin said! just edit your question and show us some of your code..

Comment: @Hitendra Let me know if you are clear with my answer.

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/file/MZnByYtA/AndroidFacebook.html.Here is the link that i have uploaded my facebook eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

```
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

This error comes when your **Access token** gets **Invalid**. So you need to **Authenticate** the user again in order to get a **Valid Access Token**.

Comment: yes i m getting same error.have you checked the code from above link?

Comment: @Hitendra U need to Uninstall your application and check. Because you cannot get another Valid Taken if this Error comes.So you need to check for Valid Session and Valid Access Token

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the permission correctly.

Comment: can u tell me where i need to change it?

Comment: I have added the permission  "publish_stream" but still getting same response.

Comment: Ok please post your code so that I can help you in better way.

Comment: Here is the link that you can download my code.http://www.4shared.com/file/e_Tov9Uj/AndroidFacebook.html?